# How to zoom webpages in Browser?

Tags: browser, webbrowser-app

There is an application called Browser(webbrowser-app) in Ubuntu 14.04. Is there any way to zoom the pages which are viewed in it?

Comment: ctrl+ wont work?

Comment: @Geo: nope thats why I asked

Comment: This is still an issue for me in 16.04.

Comment: still an issue in 18.04